# Table cells(td, th) doesn't take width given in colgroup

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give min width to table cells using `col` element of `colgroup`. The `table` is wrapped by a `div` which has some width set(less than combined width of all cells set in `col`) and `overflow` of `div` is set to `auto`.

Here is my html code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .table-block {
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        .cell {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            border: 1px solid silver;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:200px;overflow: auto">
    <table class="table-block">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:300px">
            <col style="width:300px">
        </colgroup>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell"><em>2(0,2)</em></td>
            <td class="cell"><em>3(0,3)</em></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell"><em>2(0,2)</em></td>
            <td class="cell"><em>3(0,3)</em></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is cells doesn't take width from `col`. It is trying to fit themselves in the wrapper `div`. I want that the cells take the proper width given and a scrollbar should appear. I have a solution that I set `table` width set to the total width I need. This would require me to update `table` width every time I insert new column by JavaScript.

My Solution -

```
<div style="width:200px;overflow: auto">
        <table class="table-block" style="width:600px">
        <!-- table things -->
</div>
```

Is it a right thing to do? And why it happens?

jsFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/moazzam_khan/QQ86J/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that ultimately the table defaults to 100% width of the container, and its inner elements are unable to surpass this without their content forcing it to do so. The same happens when attempting to give a `tr` or `td` a width greater than the table's own.

Your fix is pretty much the way I'd do it. The only change I'd make is:

```
<div style" ... overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden;">
```

This way a scroll bar won't appear down the side on older versions of IE.

This of course assumes that you only want your table to scroll horizontally.